# What could cause SameSite cookie to be overriden in AWS when set by Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, samesite

SameSite has finally effected us and it's been a doozy for me.

First I followed this thread: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28297, and updated rake and my session_store to set SameSite=none, secure.

That led me to updating puma so that I could run rails locally to test it, and all was well except that our CI/CD failed because having SameSite/Secure in the test environment failed. That was fine enough that I just don't set it to run during automated tests.

So I just did this to make sure that it existed on prod and staging, but wouldn't effect dev/test:

```
# session_store.rb
if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
  Rails.application.config.session_store(:cookie_store, key: '_c3_session', same_site: :none, secure: true)
else
  Rails.application.config.session_store(:cookie_store, key: '_c3_session')
end
```

But once that deployed to staging it actually stopped the cookie from coming down at all, so we could not log in.

Finally I installed this gem: https://github.com/pschinis/rails_same_site_cookie. I ran through it locally on http and https and it worked exactly as expected, so I deployed it and it made it through the tests just fine.

Once deployed, the cookie is coming down but is not coming down as SameSite=none or Secure. So I'm left to believe that somewhere somehow in our Elastic Beanstalk config is something overriding this. But no one on my team has been able to give me any direction.

```
puma  -> 4.3.3
rails -> 5.2.6.2
rack  -> 2.1.2
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I can't think of anything in EB configs or ELBs which would override an application-set cookie. So I suspect the cookie is not being set as you think it is. I would recommend SSH-ing into an Elastic Beanstalk staging app server and checking to see if the app servers are *really* responding to requests with the appropriate cookie. (i.e., doing a `curl` to the locally running web app). Only if the cookie is there can you be sure nginx or ELB is doing something weird.

Comment: @ChrisW., I got ssh access. What `curl` command should I be running to hit the locally running app?